# extending helper inputRadioGroup play2

Tags: scala, templates, radio-group, playframework-2.1

I have created my own field constructor by following the [docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaFormHelpers), the html
for my fields are rendered according to my needs.
Now I want to extend `@helper.inputRadioGroup` to conform to my needs.

My current template looks like this:

```
@(smsReviewForm: Form[SmsReview], grades: Seq[Grade]) 

@helper.inputRadioGroup(smsReviewForm("grade"),
            options = grades.map(g => g.value.toString -> g.name)
        )
```

it results in:

```
<div class="clearfix ">
<label for="grade">grade</label>
  <span class="buttonset" id="grade">   
      <input type="radio" id="grade_1" name="grade" value="1">
      <label for="grade_1">Brilliant</label>    
      <input type="radio" id="grade_2" name="grade" value="2">
      <label for="grade_2">Good</label>    
      <input type="radio" id="grade_3" name="grade" value="3" checked="">
      <label for="grade_3">Ok</label>    
  </span>
<span class="help-inline">Numeric</span>
</div>
```

What I want is to create a `@helper.customInputRadioGroup` that would render:

```
<div class="clearfix ">
<label for="grade">grade</label>
  <span class="buttonset" id="grade">   
      <input type="radio" id="grade_1" name="grade" value="1" class="hover-star star_on">
      <input type="radio" id="grade_2" name="grade" value="2" class="hover-star star_on">
      <input type="radio" id="grade_3" name="grade" value="3" checked="" class="hover-star star_on">      
  </span>
<span class="help-inline">Numeric</span>
</div>
```

How and where could I implement my own customInputRadioGroup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see how the other view helpers are done in the [play sourcecode](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper)

If you put the following code into `views.helper` of your project you should get what you need:

```
@(field: play.api.data.Field, options: Seq[(String,String)], args: (Symbol,Any)*)(implicit handler: FieldConstructor, lang: play.api.i18n.Lang)

@input(field, args:_*) { (id, name, value, htmlArgs) =>
  <span class="buttonset" id="@id">
    @options.map { v =>
      <input type="radio" id="@(id)_@v._1" name="@name" value="@v._1" @(if(value == Some(v._1)) "checked" else "") @toHtmlArgs(htmlArgs)>
    }
  </span>
}
```

I wonder whether it is really neccessary to create a custom view helper just to leave out the extra labels, maybe you can achieve the same visual effect with a bit css.

Comment: Well in this case you are correct. Implementing a custom helper is a bit overkill, but my main purpose of this question is how one should implement a custom helper. I could not find that. So this was perfect! Thank you!